# Terminate an external program and close all its active windows with python

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, terminate, taskkill

I am working from a windows platform. I have been learning different ways to launch an external process using python. Using my own examples I can:

```
os.system("C:\mainfolder\menu.exe C:\others\file1.inp C:\others\file2.inp")
```

or

```
os.popen("C:\mainfolder\menu.exe C:\others\file1.inp C:\others\file2.inp")
```

or

```
subprocess.call(["C:\mainfolder\menu.exe","C:\others\file1.inp" "C:\others\file2.inp"])
```

where:

menu.exe: is my external program.

file1 and file2: are input files to my external program.

All the above works perfectly fine, but I cannot find the way to terminate the process, including its active window for any of these cases, without having to click on the close icon from the top right of the launched window. 
However, if I type taskkill /im menu.exe on the command prompt I manage what I am looking for.

Is there any way to get the same using python?. Just looking for something simple as I do not know too much Python.

I tried with:

```
    os.system("taskkill /im menu.exe")
```

but it does not close the window that my external program launches.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use the subprocess.call() wrapper, try instantiating a `Popen` object from the subprocess module. It works the same way as call(), but you instead get an object wrapping the low-level process handler from the OS. This wrapper has a method called `terminate`, which should do what you're looking for.

Comment: I tried: child = subprocess.Popen(['C:\mainfolder\menu.exe','C:\others\file1.inp','C:\others\file2.inp'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE) to launch my program and subprocess.Popen.terminate(child) to terminate. However the window does not close yet, plus I get and Access denied error

Answer (score 0):

Keep a list of all the process id's, (`PID`), of the tasks that you start and then send them a terminate signal.

**BTW - Use with care** - *if the process you started has already finished it's PID may have been reused by something that doesn't belong to you!*

Comment: The program finishes by itself, but it leaves the window that it launches open. I am not sure how to do this, when I close it from the command line, it says:  SUCESS: Sent termination signal to the process "menu.exe" with PID 4512. How to send that order from python?.

Answer (score 0):

try like this: usin `subprocess`

```
import subprocess
child = subprocess.Popen(['commad','arg1,'arg2'....],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = child.communicate()   # will give you (stdoutdata,stderrdata)
# if you want to kill this process
child.kill() # sends SIGKILL signal
```

Comment: I have tried this code, but I still need to close the launched window manually. Once I close the window manually, the child.communicate() and the child.kill() get executed. If I don't press on the close icon of the window, my script does not go further. Where is the problem here?.

Comment: try this `import os` then `os.kill(child.pid,9)`

Comment: I think that the system does not know that my process has finished, that's why it does not respond to any of the os.kill or child.kill() or subprocess.terminate() commands.